# 777 Alternative for PHP

Tags: php, permissions

I am using imagejpeg to upload a picture to a folder .. The imagejpeg function only works if the folder has 777 permission and fails otherwise. Since 777 permission is totally unsafe, I'm wondering what can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: You could change the owner to the user who runs the script and set `755` to it

Comment: How do you know his system has the `www-data` user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask your sysadmin to change the PHP handler from dso to suphp.

Comment: I am the sysadmin .. how can I change it

Comment: There are numerous documents and discussions if you Google it.

Comment: How would changing the PHP handler from dso to suphpthis help?

Comment: This fixed it .. I just had to do some reading. Since I was using WHM/cPanel all I did is Log into WHM and navigate to: Main >> Service Configuration >> Configure PHP and SuExec

Comment: Glad I could be of help! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The PHP script runs as whatever user your webserver is running under, or if you're using a webhosting company, it probably runs as your own username. You are correct, 777 is unsafe, therefore as zerkms mentioned, change it to 755 and make sure it is owned by the proper username that runs the script.

You can find that username by looking at the username that created these files while you were running undrer `777` permission.

Comment: Normally the user is "nobody" and giving it write access means giving the whole world write access as any write attempt will be accomplished by calling the web server process and that will again be "nobody".

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind; if you set your PHP handler to suPHP, then most likely your PHP scripts will have full permission over all of your files.

Then you can keep your folders and files 755 instead of 777 which will prevent other users on the same server to access and edit your files. However, the disadvantage is that one php shell can take control of your entire account directory and everything within. Make sure your script doesn't have any RFI vulnerabilities or any vulnerabilities that may allow bad guys to execute php commands.